# Split ARRAY into chunks as they appear in sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I got an array of objects which I need to make into three chunks in the sequence as they are in the original array. For eg.

```
let arr = [{1},{2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}];
```

This array needs to be split like this:

```
let newArray = {a:[{1},{4},{7},{10},...}], b:[{2},{5},{8}], c:[{3},{6},{9}]};
```

Comment: The expected result is not an array

Comment: That expected data structure is not possible in JS. Do you want object with arrays as values? Like this: `{a:[1,4,7,10,...], b:[2,5,8], c:[3,6,9]};`

Comment: Fixed it, thanks @MorKadosh.

Comment: That is still not viable. Arrays in JavaScript don't have keys.

Comment: My bad, fixed it @Esszed.

Comment: @Esszed -  Actually arrays do have keys - the numerical index (zero indexed) of the item in the array is its key.

Comment: You are of course right. But cannot hold named key value pairs like OP had it. Now he has different issues as he is creating objects inside the arrays without these pairs.

Comment: The elements of the input array are not valid JS objects. If `{1}` is an object, it needs `key:value` pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reduce` can distribute each value on its slot based on the index

As you need `a,b,c` rather than `0,1,2` , a small mapping is needed here `mapNumLetter`

```js
let arr = ["{1}","{2}", "{3}", "{4}", "{5}", "{6}", "{7}", "{8}", "{9}", "{10}"];



// let newArray = {a:[{1},{4},{7},{10},...}], b:[{2},{5},{8}], c:[{3},{6},{9}]};

const mapNumLetter = {
  0:"a",
  1:"b",
  2:"c"
}

const newArray = arr.reduce((acc,cur,i) => {
  acc[mapNumLetter[i%3]].push(cur);
  return acc
},{a:[],b:[],c:[]})

console.log(newArray)
```

( as `{1} , {2}` ... are not valid objects, i changed them to literals `"{1}" , "{2}"` ... )

Comment: Marking this as correct as this is the shortest and very precise way, and matched my initial thought of dividing the initial array through REMAINER method. Just that I could not create the logic TBW.

Answer (score 1):

{1} is not a valid js structure

assuming than arr is an array of object you can :

- generate a rolling char index with  `String.fromCharCode(current + 97)`
- use an object to have char index

```js
let arr = [{name:1},{name:2}, {name:3}, {name:4}, {name:5}, {name:6}, {name:7}, {name:8}, {name:9}, {name:10}];

function transform(theArray, chunkValue) {
  let finalObject = {};
  let current = 0;
  let currentIndex;
  
  theArray.forEach(element => {
    currentIndex = String.fromCharCode(current + 97);
    if (!finalObject[currentIndex]) {
      finalObject[currentIndex] = [];
    }
    finalObject[currentIndex].push(element);
    current++;
    if (current === chunkValue) {
      current = 0;
    }
  });
  
  console.log(finalObject);
  return finalObject;
}

transform(arr, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this approach would be useful

```js
const data = [{1:1}, {2:2}, {3:3}, {4:4}, {5:5}, {6:6}, {7:7}, {8:8}, {9:9}, {10:10}];

const chunk = (arr, n) => arr.length ? [arr.slice(0, n), ...chunk(arr.slice(n), n)] : [];

const chunks = chunk(data, 3);
const rotated = chunks[0].map((_, colIndex) => chunks.map(row => row[colIndex]));
const result = rotated.map((arr, index) => 
  ({ [index]: arr.filter(Boolean) }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```